# Calculating relative item positions based on camera position and rotation

Tags: javascript, math, 2d, game-engine

For a 2d game, I have these concepts:

- stage: container in which items and cameras are placed.
- item: a visible entity, located on a certain point in the world, anchored from center.
- camera: an invisible entity, used to generate relative images of world, located on a certain point in the world, anchored from center.

In the illustrations, you can see how they are related, and what the end result should be.

[image: image 1]
[image: image 2]

Here is the code I have: (dumbed down to make it easier to read)

Note1: This is not happening on canvas, so I will not use canvas translation or rotation (and even then, I don't think it would make the problem any easier).

Note2: Item and camera positions are center coordinates.

```
var sin = Math.sin(rotationRad);
var cos = Math.cos(rotationRad);

var difX = item.x - camera.x;
var difY = item.y - camera.y;
var offsetX = camera.width / 2;
var offsetY = camera.height / 2;

var view.x = (cos * difX) - (sin * difY) + _Ax + _Bx;
var view.y = (sin * difX) + (cos * difY) + _Ay + _By;
```

This is supposed to calculate an items new position by:

- calculating new position of item by rotating it around camera center
- (_A*) adjusting item position by offsetting camera position
- (_B*) adjusting item position by offsetting camera size

I tried several different solutions to use for _A* and _B* here, but none of them work.

What is the correct way to do this, and if possible, what is the explanation?

Comment: Are you trying to convert world coordinates to camera coordinates?

Comment: Yes, but usual approach needs some adjustment here, because camera coordinates refer to the camera's center.

Comment: OK, so you have an object, say a Circle, and you know the world coordinates of its center. You also have a Camera whose position is the center of its viewport (world). You want to know the coordinates of the Circle having Camera position (center of viewport) as origin. Am i correct?

Comment: Or do you want to know Circle coords wrt top-left corner of the Camera viewport?

Comment: Yes, but you should also include camera rotation (around it's center).

Comment: Sorry yes to what i probably added the second question while you were writing

Answer (score 0):

You first subtract new origin position from object position. You then rotate it by the inverse of the rotation. New origin can be camera position of top left corner of viewport. Of course if you know viewport center its top left corner is computed by subtracting half of its dimensions.

Like this:

```
var topLeft = Camera.Position - Camera.Size / 2;

var newPosition = Object.Position - topLeft;

newPosition = Rotate(newPosition, -camera.Angle);
```

Rotation is very simple:

```
rotatedX = x * cos(angle) - y * sin(angle)
rotatedY = y * cos(angle) + x * sin(angle)
```

Comment: When you translate camera's center location:
`var topLeft = Camera.Position - Camera.Size / 2;`
this is not taking camera rotation in account. Translating to corner should be done after rotating the camera. Because the amount you need to translate (camera.size/2 in your example), is a different amount on both axises because of rotation.

Comment: Mmm... TopLeft is computed in world coords so no need to add rotation, ain't it?

Comment: And you can always rotate the object first. Remember to negate the angle.